# Send emails to multiple users using PHP/Javascript

Tags: php, smtp, email

I was trying to find an easier way to send e-mails to all my clients using our database (MySQL). I wanted to see if there is a way that it can select all the e-mails of my clients and I can add message, Subject and send it to all of my clients from my website rather than copying each of the mail.

Is there a way to integrate SMTP to do this? either using PHP or javascript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are about 5,247 ways. See these:

- [PEAR Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail)
- [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)
- [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/)
- [`Zend_Mail`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html)

Those are all good (and not the only ones). It is up to you to pick the one that best suits your purpose, there is no "single best" library.

Comment: Those are all good - I like PHPMailer the best, especially the way it interfaces with GMail

Answer (score 0):

I use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) .. it works wonders for me.

```
*  Send emails using SMTP, sendmail, postfix or a custom Transport implementation of your own
* Support servers that require username & password and/or encryption
* Protect from header injection attacks without stripping request data content
* Send MIME compliant HTML/multipart emails
* Use event-driven plugins to customize the library
* Handle large attachments and inline/embedded images with low memory use



require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

//Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('localhost', 25);

//Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

//Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

//Send the message
$numSent = $mailer->batchSend($message);

printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);

/* Note that often that only the boolean equivalent of the
   return value is of concern (zero indicates FALSE)

if ($mailer->batchSend($message))
{
  echo "Sent\n";
}
else
{
  echo "Failed\n";
}
```

read more here .. 
http://swiftmailer.org/docs/batchsend-method